# Chinese writings on this movie plane

Tags: character-identification, movies

I'm trying to figure what characters and what meaning is in the Chinese writing on this plane. This image comes from the first Indiana Jones movie, so it may be possible that there are mistakes in it, but I would love to know what characters are being used.

I tried to guess, using Google Translate, and so far, without being sure, all I have is "东東西東-".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: Air East Asia]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It literally means "East Asia West Asia Airlines":

> 东亚西亚航 - Simplified
>
> 東亞西亞航 - Traditional

However, the character for Asia is written the way it is in Japanese: `亜`. As far as I know, there's no deep meaning behind the choice of `亜` (or for the bizarre name). It's from an Indiana Jones movie and the airline is fictional. In answering this question, I found the [Wikia entry](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Air_East_Asia) for it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've also seen the wikia article before coming here, but the chinese name there is much longer than the one on the plane and I don't know why. Thanks anyway.